# How do I post a hidden incrementing id?

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

So I got a little (step) form were I post all kinds of stuff. Now every time I create a new `$step`, I would like to have an incrementing `order_id` stored as well. What is the right way to do this?

My code so far:

`<input type="hidden" name="order" value="{{ isset($step) ? '' : $step->order }}">`

PS: I know the `isset` is pointless, but I know the magic happens inside the `value` attribute.

Comment: A database would be a good place to store a value.

Comment: Yeah? I got a column inside my database named `order`.

Comment: Post your controller code?

Comment: Slight little sneaky edit there

Answer (score 0):

```
if (array_key_exists('order', $_POST)) { $value = (empty($_POST['order'])) ? '' : $_POST['order'];  }
```

**Add on:**

`isset()` checks if is $_POST['order'] set, $_POST['order'] could be anything not null.

`array_key_exists()` checks if is 'order' key exists in $_POST or not.

`empty()` is used to check is $_POST['order'] is empty or null or not.

Comment: Can you explain your solution?

Comment: Edited the answer :).